# JMeter - How to call request until received response containing specific attributes?

Tags: testing, jmeter, mqtt, stress-testing

## **Situation**

I am preparing a JMeter test plan to test against AWS Device provisioning MQTT API.
The flow is:

1. connect to AWS IoT Core endpoint
2. make `CreateKeysAndCertificate` request until receiving a success response as the below one (as there is a 10 times requests per second quota limit in aws)

```json
{
    "certificateId": "string",
    "certificatePem": "string",
    "privateKey": "string",
    "certificateOwnershipToken": "string"
}
```

3. extract `certificateOwnershipToken` from the success response to make `RegisterThing` request until receiving a success response (as there is a 10 times requests per second quota limit in aws)

```json
{
    "certificateOwnershipToken": "string",
    "parameters": {
        "string": "string",
        ...
    }
}
```

If the no. of requests exceeds AWS quota limits, the response would be as the below one

```
{
    "statusCode":412,
    "errorCode": "Throttled",
    "errorMessage": "Rate limit exceeded"
}
```

## Problems in my test plan

My test plan is as below pics, there are two problems

1. I want to make 500 success requests, but now the test plan only make 500 requests(including those fails)
2. I need to use `certificateOwnershipToken` from each success request for each thread to make `RegisterThing` request, but now `certificateOwnershipToken` would be the default value `not_found` even if `CreateKeysAndCertificate` request is successful

What are the problems in my test plan and how to fix them? Thank you.

[image: My test plan]

[image: User defined variable]

[image: thread group properties]

[image]

[image]

[AWS Device provisioning MQTT API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/fleet-provision-api.html#create-keys-cert)

[JMeter MQTT plugin github page](https://github.com/xmeter-net/mqtt-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

There are following problems in your Test Plan:

1. The condition in While Controller should be inverted, currently it repeats the request until `certificateOwnershipToken` is not equal to `not_found` and my expectation is that you should repeat the request until it equals and stop repeating the request once the value will differ. Moreover you should be using [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function for performance reasons instead of __javaScript().
2. If there is a rate limiting for the `certificateOwnershipToken` request you shouldn't be sending requests at the rate above this limit, consider using an appropriate [JMeter Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) like [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) so JMeter would send at most 10 requests per second

Comment: 1. Except for the performance issue, i do not understand what is my error. Could you please explain more or show me how to do it? 
2. As my senior requests, my seniors want to simulate the IoT devices retry making request when encountering the limit error